# Kendo UI Grid, How to add parameter to datasource read url and refresh grid?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I have single page application with KendoUI and AngularJs. I have two grid with two controllers. When I select first grid row (movie), I want to pass movieId to second controller and get actors for this movie.

Here my second controller:

```
myApp.controller("ActorsCtrl", function ($scope, $rootScope) {

    $rootScope.$on("SetMovieId", function (event, movieId) {
        alert(movieId);
        $scope.movieId = movieId;
        $scope.actorsGrid.dataSource.read();
        $scope.actorsGrid.dataSource.refresh();
    });

    $scope.actorsGrid = {
        dataSource: {
            type: "application/json",
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/Actors/GetActors",
                    data: { movieId: $scope.movieId }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 5,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverSorting: true
        },
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        dataBound: function () {
            this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
        },
        columns: [{
            field: "Name",
            title: "Name",
            width: "120px"
        }, {
            field: "BirthDate",
            title: "Birth Date",
            template: "#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(BirthDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'MM/dd/yyyy') #",
            width: "120px"
        }]
    };
});
```

Is this movieId adding correct?
How to refresh grid?
My example doesn't work :(

Answer (score -1):

Kendo UI Datasource has event requestStart where you can pass parameters to request url.

```js
var urlFormat = "/actors/{0}";

var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: "/actors/",
      dataType: "jsonp"
    }
  },
  requestStart: function(e) {
    e.options.url = kendo.format(urlFormat, movieId);
  }
});
```

Comment: "e.options.url = "... results in: TypeError: Cannot set property 'url' of undefined